# Periodic Table of Elements Resonant Frequencies (Resonant, Emitted and Absorbtion)

Tags: atomic-physics, resource-recommendations, resonance, elements

I'm looking for a nice PTE chart that gives the frequencies of each element by Fraunhofer scale.
Any help?

Comment: That would be a vast amount of data! You probably need to be more selective. Do you mean the strongest few transitions from the ground state? (and how does your request relate to hyperfine structure and fine structure and magnetic transitions? What precision do you need?

Comment: I very much like the way Fraunhofer derived the resonant spectra of the elements as a series of banded omissions from white light. The complexity of the atom implies harmonic overtones as a property of elements and compounds: I am attempting to sonify the Periodic Table. Cheers mate. M